Bigquery SQL query to remove customers with negative values
I have a dataset where each observation represents monthly sales per customer. A customer can have multiple months with positive sales and some months with negative sales. I want to remove all customers with at least one month of negative sales. I've tried these two examples, but I still have customers with negative sales. What could be the issue?
Example 1:
SELECT *
FROM table_A a
WHERE a.customer NOT IN (
    SELECT customer
    FROM table_A sub_a
    WHERE sub_a.sales < 0
  )
ORDER BY sales;

Example 2:
SELECT a.*
FROM table_A a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM table_A sub_a
  WHERE sub_a.customer = a.customer
    AND sub_a.sales < 0
)
ORDER BY a.sales;

Any suggestions?

please add the example of the data; the input and the expected output.

Guessing something to do with the datatype of the columns. The following thing worked for me using your method too.
Select * Into #CustSales from 
(
Select 'A' Customer, 100 sales, 1 mth Union
Select 'A' Customer, 100 sales, 2 mth Union
Select 'A' Customer, -100 sales, 3 mth Union
Select 'B' Customer, 500 sales, 1 mth Union
Select 'B' Customer, 100 sales, 2 mth Union
Select 'C' Customer, 200 sales, 1 mth Union
Select 'C' Customer, 400 sales, 2 mth 
) A


;With CustNegativeSales as
(
Select Customer
From #CustSales
Where sales < 0
)

Select * from #CustSales B
Where Customer Not IN (Select Customer From CustNegativeSales)

Select * from #CustSales C
Where Customer Not In (Select Customer
                    From #CustSales
                    Where sales < 0)

Drop Table #CustSales

FiddleQuery
